# UIAlertView delegate to another class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates, uialertview

A ViewContoller (`SecondViewController`) which is not visible shows an `UIAlertView` like this:

```
ViewController *viewc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
UIAlertView *alert =  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fehler" message:@"Message" delegate:viewc.delegate cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] ;

[alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

In ViewController.h delegate is definded like this:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) id<UIAlertViewDelegate> delegate;`

But the delegate methods don't get called in `ViewController.h`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Greg it is the integrated method `[alertView show]`

Comment: Yes sure I haven't noticed that. Do you just allocated the viewc and try to handle UIAlertViewDelegate on it? I believe you should present the viewc if you want to handle delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to define a delegate for the second viewController and then assign that delegate to the UIAlertView delegate. Instead set the delegate of the UIAlertView to the second viewController.

```
ViewController *viewc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
UIAlertView *alert =  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fehler" message:@"Message" delegate:viewc cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] ;

[alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

However, you do need to make sure that the second viewController conforms to the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol and implements the required methods.

Ex.

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@end
```

Also, remove this property from the second viewController as it is not needed
`@property (strong, nonatomic) id<UIAlertViewDelegate> delegate;`.

Comment: The methods still don't get fired.

Comment: Does the second viewController conform to the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol?

Comment: Yes, both ViewControllers do.

Comment: Only the second ViewController needs to conform to the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol, but really it should be the presenting viewController. Anyways, I just tested this and it works for me. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved it now with `NSNotificationCenter`